# C# get data from SQL Server async .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have an app that displays a big data table downloaded from SQL Server, and refreshes it every 5 seconds, but the whole SQL query and data sorting takes about 0.8~1sec, and I wanted to make it async because I want to avoid the UI freezing for that time every 5 sec.

I read a lot about this, but my code won't work, so far I got this:

Reader method:

```
public static IEnumerable<ComputerStats> ComputerstatsReader(SqlDataReader reader,
DateTime currentDateTime)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return ComputerStatsBuilder(reader, currentDateTime);
    }
}
```

I got a builder too, but no use to link it here.

And here comes the async task:

```
public static async Task AsyncSql(string connetionString, string sqlQuery,
ObservableCollection<ComputerStats> _collection)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        try
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                if (_collection.Count != 0) 
                    _collection.Clear();

                foreach (ComputerStats Item in ComputerstatsReader(reader, currentDateTime))
                {
                    _collection.Add(Item);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I call it:

```
public void SqlGetData(int ihuman, ObservableCollection<ComputerStats> _collection)
{            
    string connetionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Connection Timeout=3", 
    Variables.ServerArray[ihuman], Variables.SqlDataBase, Variables.SqlUserName,Variables.SqlPassword);
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM COMPUTERS";                 

    Task task = AsyncSql(connetionString, sqlQuery, _collection, source.Token);
    task.Wait();
}
```

My problem is that it stops at `await conn.OpenAsync();` and didn't even give me an error, it just never loads.

Did I made any errors, or am I doing this right?

(without async it worked like a charm, so the SQL Server is perfectly alright)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you have to propagate the await and async into the timer event

Comment: @marc_s thank you, I made SqlGetDAta an async task, and await it in the timer tick, now it all works! now I have to figure out, how to stop the UI lagg, i guess call the task like: await Task.Run(() => SqlGetData(0, Collection));
but then Collection will be on a different thread, isnt it? so I guess i have to make a Task with retun with a new Collection or smth

Comment: @Grumbler85 Oh now I see I posted my comment at the wrong user :D
so just wanted to thank you for your suggestion.
now I will dive into the problem that I need this task run in the background and get data from it. anyway cheers!

Comment: If it is an WPF App you can use System.Windows.DispatcherTimer (at least I think it is called that) - if you go async all the way starting with the public async void TimerTick it should work.